# When i make an typo error in the rails console, do i have to start all over again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I have previously entered a few commands then i made a mistake and type pin.save and press enter,instead of typing @pin.save.

Do i have to restart the rails console or is their a way to continue with my previous work in the console?

In addition I'm following a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

After typing `pin.save`, you can type `@pin.save` it will reflect the change. No need to start console agian.

`rails console` is only restarted when there will be a change in model or any other place which needs to restart the console. Then you can restart the console by typing the below in console and hit enter:-

```
reload!
```

Comment: [padawancoder~/12_in_12/pin_board]  $ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0.rc3)
Error : 'load /Users/King-Gorge/.irbrc' : uninitialized constant RB
2.1.0 :001 > @pin.save
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):1

Comment: It means that `@pin` in only a instance variable and not the object of a model, so it is throwing error as `undefined method 'save' for nil:NilClass`. So initialize a new object of that model again as `@object = Model.new` or with some values as `@object = Model.new(field1: value1, field2: value2)`